# I need to re-enable MFA after reinstalling the DUO app

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have accidentally removed the DUO app from my mobile. After installing it, I need to re-scan the code, but I cannot remove the current MFA enabled phone number from the settings

Multi-factor Authentication

Enroll in MFA, edit the phone number associated with your MFA account.
StatusEnrolled

disabling MFA and re enabling it

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried or errors you have encountered. Also add more tags so the question is visible to a larger audience

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable MFA (ALTER USER your_username SET DISABLE_MFA = TRUE) and then re-enroll in MFA through the UI preferences. What error are you receiving?

Comment: Suzy's point is valid, you should get one of the system_admins/account_admins to run the above SQL. And you should allows have one not used account_admin that doesn't use MFA so you can get it. Failing all those, you will need to contact support to unlock your account.